# Javascript scrolling code

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a link to some code that i would like to implement.

http://jsfiddle.net/g7gYy/12/

I am having a bit of trouble working out where to place the code and to actually get it too work.

Here is an html file that I have uploaded: http://www.canning.co.nz/Game/testmarquee.html

Can I please have some help with this?

thanks

Comment: You need to include jQuery in html file you provied.

Comment: Mateusz W: Can you please advise me on what to do to add jQuery? I have not used it before.

Comment: check my answer for that

Answer (score 1):

First you didnt added jquery lib to your page add it.

```
<script src="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Next put all your code in document ready because before document get ready your code get executed but elements are not ready to do some operations

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $text = $('.text-to-scroll', $marquee);
    var textWidth = $text.width();

    var $marquee = $('#marquee');
    var marqueeWidth = $marquee.width();
    $marquee.css('height', $text.height());

    function animateLoop()
    {
        //First lets put if out of view to the left
        $text.css('left', -textWidth);
        //Now it's out of view, change it's display from none to block
        $text.css('display', 'block');

        //Now we can animate it so that if scrolls across the screen
        //http://api.jquery.com/animate/
        $text.animate({ 'left' : marqueeWidth }, 10000, 'linear', animateLoop);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript file link is not good.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="marquee.js">
```

make sure the marquee.js file is in the same folder as your testmarquee.html page.

### **Later Edit:**

Ow, scratch that, i was wrong, Mateusz was in fact right.:D